# Experiencing an undefined function error, using SQL queries with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

I am simply trying to have this one button implement a function that simply shows the users scores for the game overall. This data is updated in an Access DB each time the user plays the game. I don't know if this is an issue with my SQL queries or with my JavaScript coding. I simply need a popup window to display this information when the user clicks this button. Code is as follows:(Just a portion of the code that's supposed to display the popup window, nothing more.)

```
<button onclick="showscores()" style=" top: 155px; left: 160px; position: absolute;"> Show scores

var user = "FOO";

var myDB = new ACCESSdb("C:\\Users\\FOO\\Users.mdb", {showErrors:true});

function showscores(){
    // select and retrieve the user info data , containing the score data 
    window.alert(myDB.query("SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE UserName = 'username'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your query - a missing closing double quote. It should be:

```
window.alert(myDB.query("SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE UserName = 'username'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

myDB should be declared within the function unless declared globally, its not clear in your example if that is the case.

```
function showscores(){
    var myDB = new ACCESSdb("C:\\Users\\FOO\\Users.mdb", {showErrors:true});
    // select and retrieve the user info data , containing the score data 
    window.alert(myDB.query("SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE UserName = 'username'"));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did declare it globally. Sorry for the ambiguity. Now that I fixed the double quote syntax error, I'm getting back a false value from my database.

Comment: Cool, I suggest opening a new question for that as it may be one of many things, file path, table name, column name etc

Comment: Okay , will make a new question then.